# CouchDB Group By Values, Date Range

Tags: view, couchdb

I have a bunch of documents in a CouchDB instance with the following data:

```
{
    "_id": "[string based ID generated by CouchDB]",
    "action": "view",
    "group": [Integer representing a group number],
    "date": [Javascript timestamp]
}
```

I can use the following to group data by group and action and to get the total number of actions per group:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.group, doc.action], [1, 1]);
}
```

(With reduce simply being `_sum`).

The issue is, this fetches data from *all* groups, whereas I only want the data from a single group (e.g. from group 1).

Also, I know I can do something like this to filter by date, but how would I combine it with the above to filter by date and by group ID?

```
function(doc) {
    var then = new Date(Date.parse(doc['Event Date']));
    var fatalities = 0;
    if (doc['Total Fatal Injuries']!="") {
        fatalities = parseInt(doc['Total Fatal Injuries']);
    }
    emit([then.getFullYear(), then.getMonth()], [1, fatalities]);
}
```

(From https://cloudant.com/blog/mapreduce-from-the-basics-to-the-actually-useful/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your map() and reduce() functions correct already, you simply need to pass `reduce=true&group_level=1&startkey=[<group id>]&endkey=[<group id>.toString() + "a"]` to the view.

As for the filtering by date, you can use the same strategy. Using the group level, you can see sums per year and per month.

Comment: Yep, that was it-- I needed to specify the start and end keys as the same group ID, and use `{}` in the endkey to specify "everything" for all other keys.